# Comparing arrays of hashes for equality in any order

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, compare

Let's say I have two arrays that consist of hashes, structured similarly like this:

```
array = [{:name => "John", 
            :surname => "Smith", 
            :family => {:mom => "Cathy", 
                        :father => "Joe"} 
         },{:name => "Kevin", 
            :surname => "Smith", 
            :family => {:mom => "Jessica", 
                        :father => "Bob"} 
         }]
```

What is the best and fastest way to compare two arrays like this if both of them have about 10000 elements/people (hashes) in the array?

The hashes in the second array may not be in the same order as in first, but if the elements are same then the arrays are equal.
Also the comparison should be able to locate the difference (if there is any) not only show that they are not equal.

Comment: The first part can easily be handled fairly easily as is noted by the basic answers below. The second part is very complicated because you have not defined what should be categorized as a difference. If the names are the same but the family is different this is a difference but what do you want shown. What kind of differences do you want shown and how? A better understanding of what you are doing with this information would be extremely beneficial

Answer (score 9):

```
diff = (array1 - array2) + (array2 - array1)
equality = diff.empty?
```

Comment: Good, but since the OP wants to know the differences, you might write `in_1_not_2 = array1 - array2; in_2_not_1 = array2 - array1; equality = in_1_not_2.empty? && in_2_not_1.empty?`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes, "difference" is something vague, I don't know about what kind of difference OP asked :)

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'set'

def compare(array1, array2)        
  s1, s2 = array1.to_set, array2.to_set   
  if (s1 == s2)
    puts "arrays are equal"
  else
    puts "elements in array1 not in array 2: #{(s1-s2).to_a}" unless (s1-s2).empty?
    puts "elements in array2 not in array 1: #{(s2-s1).to_a}" unless (s2-s1).empty?
  end
end

a1 = [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { b: 1, a: 2 }]
a2 = [{ a: 2, b: 1 }, { b: 2, a: 1 }]
a3 = [{ a: 2, b: 1 }, { b: 0, a: 1 }]

compare(a1, a2)
  #=> arrays are equal
compare(a1, a3)
  #=> elements in array1 not in array 2: [{:a=>1, :b=>2}]
  #=> elements in array2 not in array 1: [{:b=>0, :a=>1}]
```

`(s1-s2).to_a` and `(s2-s1).to_a` are much faster than `array1-array2` and `array2-array1`, but that does not account for the overhead of creating the two sets. On balance, I don't know whether it's faster to use sets or simply use array differences.